# I can't get my navbar to expand when toggled

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to learn bootstrap 4 but I'm struggling with the navbar. I got the icon to appear at the right time then I evidently did something to mess it up, now I can't even get the icon to appear and I was never able to get the links to drop down.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <title>Home</title>
     <link href="compworks.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">           <!-- Top grandparent nav -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

              <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html">HOME</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: element ID's are NOT supposed to has # in front. # is a convention used to denote IDs when accessing them with jQuery.

<input id="one">  will be referenced as $.("#one") for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "navbar-light" and "bg-light" classes on nav tag. Background color is missing.

And remove "#" from div id. Change id="#navbarResponsive" to id="navbarResponsive"

good luck